# Typeclass for (what seems to be) a contravariant functor implementing function inversion

Tags: haskell, category-theory, category-abstractions

Lets say I have the following

```
import Control.Category (Category, (.), id)

data Invertible a b = Invertible (a -> b) (b -> a)

instance Category Invertible where
  id = Invertible Prelude.id Prelude.id
  (Invertible f f') . (Invertible g g') = 
    Invertible (f Prelude.. g) (g' Prelude.. f')

invert (Invertible x y) = Invertible y x
```

Note that the following is true:

```
invert (g . f) == invert f . invert g
```

This structure seems very similar to a [contravariant functor (wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor#Covariance_and_contravariance), as it follows the same axiom:

```
 F(g . f) = F(f) . F(g)
```

In my case, `F` is simply `invert`.

I looked at [Data.Functor.Contravariant.contramap](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/contravariant-1.3.3/docs/Data-Functor-Contravariant.html#v:contramap), which has a function of the type:

```
(a -> b) -> f b -> f a
```

But I didn't know how'd I'd implement that in my situation. For example, I can't work out a sensible choice for `f`, and in my situation, there's no function `a -> b`, just `invert`.

However, `invert` nevertheless fits the mathematical axiom of a contravariant functor, so I'm thinking I can fit this into some existing class, but I just can't find which one and how to do it. Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: You might find this blog post interesting: http://gelisam.blogspot.com/2013/07/the-commutative-monad.html

Comment: The problem, in my humble opinion, is that `invert` is a contravariant endofunctor in the category of `Invertible` whereas `Contravariant f` is a contravariant endofunctor in the category of `Hask`.

Comment: @AaditMShah, that was my guess too, but I don't know enough category theory to be confident.

Comment: You may or may not already know about the lens types `Iso s t a b = forall f p . (Functor f, Profunctor p) => p a (f b) -> p s (f t)` and `Iso' a b = Iso a a b b`. `Iso'` ends up being isomorphic to your type. This doesn't relate to your question; I just thought you might find it interesting.

Answer (score 8):

A category has two collections: objects and morphisms.

The usual Haskell prelude, and it appears that the classes in `Data.Functor.Contravariant`, only operate on a very narrow category, that is the category where types are objects and functions are morphisms, usually denoted **Hask**. The standard `Functor` class is also very narrow: they only represent *endofunctors* on **Hask**: they must take types to types and functions to functions.

Take for example the functor `Maybe`.  The way `Maybe` acts on types is just that it takes types `a` to `Maybe a`.  `Maybe` maps `Int` to `Maybe Int` and so on (I know this sounds a bit trivial).  What it does to morphisms is encoded by `fmap`: `fmap` takes `f :: (a -> b)`, a morphism between two objects in **Hask**, and maps it to `fmap f :: (Maybe a -> Maybe b)`, another morphism in **Hask** between the objects that the functor maps to.  In Haskell we could not define a `Functor` which takes e.g. `Int` to `Char` -- all Haskell `Functor`s have to be type constructors -- but in general category theory we could.

`Control.Category` generalizes a little bit: the objects of a `Control.Category` category `C` are still types[1] just like in **Hask**, but its morphisms are things of type `C a b`.  So in your example, the objects are still arbitrary types, but your morphisms are things of type `Invertible a b`.  Since your morphisms are not functions, you will not be able to use the standard `Functor` classes.

However, it's a fun exercise in building up your category theory knowhow to define a functor class which operates between `Category` categories rather than assuming **Hask**, which would capture your example. Remember, a functor acts on objects (types) *and* morphisms.

I'll leave you with that -- feel free to comment if you would like more guidance.

---

[1] Ignoring `PolyKinds`, which makes this a bit more general.

Comment: You beat me to it. I knew that the problem was because the OP was trying to marry `Prelude.id` with `Control.Category.id` and `Prelude..` with `Control.Category..`, but I didn't get the time to write an answer. I was led astray by the following blog post: http://gelisam.blogspot.com/2013/07/the-commutative-monad.html

Comment: Lets say we reverse what's found in Control.Categorical.fmap which is `r a b -> t (f a) (f b)`. Instead reverse to be `contramap :: r a b -> t (f b) (f a)`. Let r = Invertible and t = Invertible. From here we've got `contramap :: Invertible a b -> Invertible (f b) (f a)`. I guess at this point we just need "f" to be Id?

Comment: @Clinton Indeed. You would define `class (Category c, Category d) => Contravariant f c d | f c -> d, f d -> c where contramap :: c x y -> d (f y) (f x)`. Then you would define `instance Contravariant Identity Invertible Invertible where contramap (Invertible f g) = Invertible (Identity . g . runIdentity) (Identity . f . runIdentity)`. Now you have `contramap` isomorphic to `invert`. However, I doubt that you would want to use `contramap` because you would have to deal with an unnecessary `Identity` wrapper. You're better off simply using the `invert` function directly.