# Issues Generalising Functor

Tags: haskell, functor, category-theory

[Functor in Control.Categorical.Functor](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/categories-1.0.7/docs/Control-Categorical-Functor.html#t:Functor) has the following definition:

```
class (Category r, Category t) => Functor f r t | f r -> t, f t -> r where
  fmap :: r a b -> t (f a) (f b)
```

But lets say I want to have a functor from ordinary functions to [Kleisli](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#t:Kleisli) arrows (this is perhaps a silly example) .

I'd want a type like this:

```
fmap :: (Monad m) => (a -> b) -> Kleisli m a b
```

Well I can let `r = (->)`, `t = Kleisli m` to get:

```
fmap :: (Monad m) => (a -> b) -> Kleisli m (f a) (f b)
```

But then, what's `f`?! I really just want it to disappear. I could use the [Identity](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Identity.html#t:Identity) functor by letting `f = Identity` but then I get:

```
fmap :: (Monad m) => (a -> b) -> Kleisli m (Identity a) (Identity b)
```

which would require some messy unwrapping.

I then thought of defining Functor like this:

```
class (Category r, Category t) => Functor r t where
  type family F r t x :: *
  fmap :: r a b -> t (F r t a) (F r t b)
```

This allows me to define a Functor instance for Kleisli as follows (without an ugly Identity wrapper):

```
instance (Monad m) => Functor (->) (Kleisli m) where
  type F (->) (Kleisli m) a = a
  fmap f = Kleisli (return . f)
```

And after this, I'm pretty sure I'm at:

```
fmap :: (Monad m) => (a -> b) -> Kleisli m a b
```

Which is good.

Now, there's one issue I can identify straight away namely, for a given `r` and `t` parameters to `Functor`, the original class definition allows multiple options for `f`, whereas with my definition, `r` and `t` determine `f`. This is a serious problem, as if I define say:

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> (Maybe a -> Maybe b)
```

I can't then define:

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> ([a] -> [b])
```

As in both cases, `r = (->)` and `t = (->)`. So currently my `Functor` doesn't even replace the original Prelude version.

So there's some questions I now have:

1. Can I adjust my definition so `r` and `t` do not determine `f` (like the original version)? Or would this require [Injective Type Families](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/InjectiveTypeFamilies) (I'm happy to compile head to try this if this is the case).
2. Can I further adjust my definition so that `f` and `r` determines `t` and also `f` and `t` determines `r`?
3. After doing the above (or not if it's not possible) what are the potential impacts on type inference?
4. Are there any other bad things about my class definition as compared to the original, other than things like increased typing?
5. Are there any alternate approaches that still allow me to define the Kleisli functor without wrapping with Identity whilst being "better" that what I've proposed (more useful structure, better type inference etc).

I'm sorry the last few questions are a bit vague, I understand that type inference vs generality is often a tradeoff, but I'm just looking for some thoughts on it in this particular case.

(This question partly follows on from answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32687682/typeclass-for-what-seems-to-be-a-contravariant-functor-implementing-function-i))

Answer (score 3):

The closest you could get would be

```
class (Category r, Category t) => Functor
          (f :: *) (r :: *->*->*) (t :: *->*->*) where
  type F f x :: *
  fmap :: Tagged f ( r a b -> t (F f a) (F f b) )

instance Functor [()] (->) (->) where
  type F [()] x = [x]
  fmap = Tagged map

instance (Monad m) => Functor (Kleisli m () ()) (->) (Kleisli m) where
  type F (Kleisli m () ()) x = x
  fmap = Tagged $ \f -> Kleisli $ return . f
```

Comment: I would be tempted to use `class .. => Functor (f :: k) ...` with `PolyKinds`, and remove the dummy occurrences of `()` below. Whether this is a good idea or not, I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @chi I considered writing that myself, but I'm not really firm with PolyKinds.